# How to correctly use innerHTML to create an element (with possible children) from a html string?

Tags: javascript, string, dom, innerhtml

Note: I do **NOT** want to use any framework.

---

### The goal is just to create a function that will return an element based on an HTML string.

Assume a simple HTML Document like such:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

All functions mentioned are in included the head section and all DOM creation/manipulation is done at the end of the body in a script tag.

---

I have a function createElement that takes a well formed HTML String as an argument. It goes like this:

```
function createElement(str)
{
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = str;
  return div.childNodes;
}
```

Now this functions works great when you call it like such:

```
var e = createElement('<p id="myId" class="myClass">myInnerHTML</p>');
```

With the minor (possibly HUGE) problem that the element created isn't a 'true' element, it still has a parentNode of 'div'.  If anyone knows how to fix that, then that would be awesome.

---

Now if I call the same function with a more complex string:

```
var e = createElement('<p id="myId" class="myClass">innerHTML<h2 id="h2ID" class="h2CLASS">Heading2</h2></p>');
```

It creates TWO children instead of ONE child with another child having another child.
Once you do div.innerHTML = str.  The innerHTML instead of

```
`<p id="myId" class="myClass">innerHTML    <h2 id="h2ID" class="h2CLASS">Heading2</h2>    </p>`
```

turns to

```
`<p id="myId" class="myClass">innerHTML</p>        <h2 id="h2ID" class="h2CLASS">Heading2</h2>`
```

---

**Questions:**

1. Can I somehow get an element without a parent node after using .innerHTML?
2. Can I (in the case of the slightly complex string) get my function to return ONE element with the appropriate child instead of two elements. [It actually returns three, `<p.myClass#myId>`,`<h2.h2CLASS#h2ID>`, and another `<p>`]

Comment: (1) you can remove the nodes from the container (`removeNode`) or clone them (`cloneNode`) (2) not for that example, because of the complicated rules about how `<p>` tags work. Your `<h2>` implicitly closes the preceding `<p>` tag because `<h2>` is a block-level element (as are various others).

Comment: What pointy said <p><h2></h2></p> is not a valid html string ;)

Comment: Alright yes that makes sense.<h>'s don't go in <p> tags.  That solves that problem.

Comment: You can only use removeNode to remove CHILDREN. Edit: nvm.  Half the browsers don't support it.  Only IE strangely.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is similar to the answer from `palswim`, except that it doesn't bother with creating a clone, and uses a `while()` loop instead, always appending the node at `[0]`.

```
function createElement( str ) {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

    var elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.innerHTML = str;

    while (elem.childNodes[0]) {
        frag.appendChild(elem.childNodes[0]);
    }
    return frag;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this would probably use less overhead.

Comment: This is equivalent to the other one except that your last line should be frag.childNodes as I want the element not the fragment. Thanks! This was helpful.

Comment: @Sanchit - Glad it was helpful. :o) I went back and forth on the return value. Figured that returning the frag would offer more possibilities as it would give you the ability to append the entire fragment immediately if desired, while still retaining the possibility of iterating over the `childNodes`. Anyway, using the documentFragment solves the parent node issue.

Answer (score 4):

You'd have to attach the new element somewhere.  Try using a `DocumentFragment` object in conjunction with the `div` you created:

```
function createElement(str) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = str;
    var container = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i=0; i < div.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var node = div.childNodes[i].cloneNode(true);
        container.appendChild(node);
    }
    return container.childNodes;
}
```

It's more overhead, but it does what you want.  Note that DOM elements' `.insertAdjacentHTML` member function is coming in HTML5.

For that complex string you passed, it isn't valid XHTML syntax - you can't have a block element as a child of `<p>` (`<h2>` is a block level element).

Comment: Yes I realize why it was doing that now.  Silly mistake, been staring at it for a bit.  So I ALMOST had it, oh well.  Thanks!