# What is proper method of appending multiple lines of HTML using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm aware of `appendChild` and `createElement` but these are methods to use when I'm adding a single line of HTML. I recognize I could add a script object, or an `iframe` object using this approach, but how would I in JavaScript add 20+ lines of HTML to an existing HTML document?

I built a `search.js` file to address searching requirements of an HTML page. It works great! But I want to encapsulate my search form and CSS and was thinking I could append the data to an existing HTML document to keep things compact and more manageable.

UPDATE: So the JavaScript would be added to an existing HTML page at the bottom within two SCRIPT tags. The JS would append a string - which would be 20+ lines of HTML stringified - to an existing page, which I had hoped would render as HTML.

```
var sectionAsHtml = '' +
'<div class='xyz'>' +
' <div class='abc'>' +
'  <p>This is just an example for demonstration purposes.</p>' +
' </div>' +
'</div>';
```

I would then locate the body of my HTML using a ".getElementById" find, and then ".appendChild" the above string.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: Kind of need to know if you're just transforming raw HTML, or if you're doing this in the context of the browser that is currently displaying that HTML, or if you're the server performing templating, or what.

Comment: Client side JS adding to an existing page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `createElement()` like below:

```js
let html = `<ul>
  <li>Li 1</li>
  <li>Li 2</li>
</ul>
<div id="test">Testdiv</div>`

function createElement( str ) {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

    var elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.innerHTML = str;

    while (elem.childNodes[0]) {
        frag.appendChild(elem.childNodes[0]);
    }
    return frag;
}

let fragment = createElement(html)
document.getElementById('app').appendChild(fragment)
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <h1>The App</h1>
</div>
```

Taken from this answer to a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3662980/3744304