# AJAX TABLE : how to call a function by onclick in button on the table ? json

Tags: javascript, ajax, html-table, parameters, onclick

I need to call the function by clicking on the button passing the id of that position as a parameter, but I didn't get this ways, how do I do it using this syntax?

```
    function populateTable(data){
    var table = document.getElementById('table-sector')
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
      var row = ` <tr><td>${data[i].nome}</td>
                      <td>${data[i].sigla}</td>
                      <td>${data[i].ramal}</td>
                      <td>${data[i].email}</td>
                      <td><button onclick="populateInfo(${data[i]._id}) "type="button" class="btn btn-primary" " data-toggle="modal"
                      data-target="#info">+</button></td>
                      </td>
                  </tr>`



      table.innerHTML+= row

    }
  }

function populateInfo(data){

       console.log(data)

  }
```

Comment: sorry i did'nt got it

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `onclick="populateInfo(${data[i]._id}) "` to:

```html
onclick="populateInfo('` + data[i]._id + `')"
```

It printed out the data for me. 
Simply, you began the HTML code with a back quote, so put one before and after your variable followed by a plus sign to join the strings.

**EDIT** as you said the issue was not solved, I suggest simplifying the test for debugging purposes. Try run this snippet. If your code still does not work, the problem will be the *data input that you are passing*.
If that is the case, press CTRL SHIFT E in your browser, go to Console and try running the code again. The browser will tell you what and where the error is.

```html
<div id="table-sector"></div>
<div id="output"></div>

<script>
 
    function populateTable(data){
    var table = document.getElementById('table-sector');
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
      var row = ` <tr>
                      <td><button onclick="populateInfo('` + data[i] + `')  "type="button" class="btn btn-primary" " data-toggle="modal"
                      data-target="#info">+</button></td>
                      </td>
                  </tr>`



      table.innerHTML+= row;

    }
  }

 function populateInfo(data){
 
     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += data;
     console.log(data)

 }
 
 populateTable([1,2,3,4,5]);
</script>
```

Comment: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier ... i've tried onclick="populateInfo('` + data[i]_id `+ ')"  but it get like a String

Comment: Hello Hugo, I elaborated the answer. Hope this helps. Try running the snippet. Also, in my original answer, I mistyped one dot, maybe that was the problem. Good luck.

Comment: Hello Javier, Thanks for answering ... when i used this, i've get the values of the object like Strings. Is better than what i had before, but i need the object on this position to populate the next table (example: data.name, data._id, data.phone ...). I've tried to use "var data = JSON.parse( data )", but it didn't work!
can u tell me what i have to do ? 
btw, thankyou !

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies within using the string template. When you used string templates to create elements it is not possible to pass object arguments into event handlers because everything is a string. (Except if you make data as a global variable and change your template into this `populateInfo(data[${i}]._id)` which is not a good practice.) Instead, you should create your element from the string,  materialize it and then attach the event handler as below :

```js
const data = [{
  nome: "jhon",
  sigla: "doe",
  ramal: "ramal",
  email: "jhondoe@mail"
}, {
  nome: "jhon1",
  sigla: "doe1",
  ramal: "ramal1",
  email: "jhondoe1@mail"
}];

function populateTable(data) {
  var table = document.getElementById('table-sector')
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // using let instead of var is a must

    var row = ` <tr><td>${data[i].nome}</td>
                      <td>${data[i].sigla}</td>
                      <td>${data[i].ramal}</td>
                      <td>${data[i].email}</td>
                      <td><button  "type="button" class="btn btn-primary" " data-toggle="modal"
                      data-target="#info">+</button></td>
                      </td>
                  </tr>`
    const tr = createElement(row);
    const button = tr.querySelector("button");
    button.addEventListener("click", () => populateInfo(data[i]));
    table.appendChild(tr);

  }
}

function populateInfo(data) {
  console.log(data);
}

function createElement(str) {
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var elem = document.createElement('table');
  elem.innerHTML = str;

  while (elem.childNodes[0]) {
    frag.appendChild(elem.childNodes[0]);
  }
  return frag;
}

populateTable(data);
```

```html
<div>
  <table id="table-sector"></table>
</div>
```

`createElement` function is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3662980/12354911)